# How to get the expected string with a expression regular in testing library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, testing-library

I'm trying to test a component that, when I click in the buttons 'Adicionar ao final'(add to the end) or 'Adicionar ao início'(add to the begin), it shows something like that:

```
Id:1627223765317 Valor:1627223765317
Id:1627223765150 Valor:1627223765150
```

I want to make a test to get these renders.

Component code:

```
/* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
/* eslint-disable react/no-this-in-sfc */
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/control-has-associated-label */
/* eslint-disable react/button-has-type */
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PageDefault from '../../components/PageDefault';
import './index.scss';

function Keys() {
  const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);
  return (
    <PageDefault>
      <form onSubmit={(event) => event.preventDefault()}>
        <div className="buttons-inputs">
          <button onClick={() => setObjects([
            {
              id: +new Date().valueOf(),
              valor: +new Date().valueOf(),
            },
            ...objects,
          ])}
          >
            Adicionar ao início
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => setObjects([
            ...objects,
            {
              id: +new Date().valueOf(),
              valor: +new Date().valueOf(),
            },
          ])}
          >
            Adicionar ao final
          </button>
          <button onClick={
          () => setObjects(objects.filter((object) => object.id !== objects[0].id))
        }
          >
            Remover do início
          </button>
          <button onClick={() => {
            setObjects(objects.filter((object) => object.id !== objects[objects.length - 1].id));
          }}
          >
            Remover do final
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="lists">
          <div className="list-id">
            <h2>ID:</h2>
            {objects.map((object) => (
              <h1 key={object.id}>
                Id:
                {object.id}
                {' '}
                Valor:
                {object.valor}
              </h1>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="list-index">
            <h2>Index</h2>
            {objects.map((object, index) => (
              // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
              <h1 key={index}>
                Id:
                {object.id}
                {' '}
                Valor:
                {object.valor}
              </h1>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </PageDefault>
  );
}

export default Keys;
```

Test:

```
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Keys from './index';

describe('Testing the rendering of components', () => {
  test('if it render component prop types exemple', () => {
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Keys />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );
  });
  test('if it render component prop types exemple', () => {
    const { getByText, queryByText } = render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Keys />
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );

    fireEvent.click(getByText('Adicionar ao início'));
    expect(queryByText('Valor:^/0-9/i')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

By now, it's like: "expect(queryByText('Valor:^/0-9/i')).toBeInTheDocument();" but I think that the regex 'Valor:^/0-9/i' it's not correct. I'm getting a little bit confuse about write regex.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is not a valid regex pattern https://regex101.com/r/LjK1wR/1

Comment: ignore case with a number? `/Valor: \d{13}/i'`

Comment: Evolutionxbox, yeah! I've forgot of the brackets. I've changed it  for this:
  `const reg = new RegExp('Valor:[0-9]', 'i');
  expect(queryByText(reg)).toBeInTheDocument();` 
But it still seems that i'm not correct.

Comment: AZ_, it also didn't work for me :/